# Damp Tag Useful?

Tags: discussion, retagging, tagging

Is the [damp tag](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/damp) necessary?

I don't feel it's very resourceful or descriptive.

I couldn't see anyone showing interested in subscribing or/utilizing the damp tag. In the context of the one question tagged here. It might be more appropriate to use the Diagnosis tag. What are your thoughts?

Please be kind. This is my first meta question/post ever.

Comment: Obviously, it should be a synonym for [moist](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/1857/)...

Answer (score 4):

I retagged. Damp seems useless in the question; although it is describing the environment, the environment would not be damp as the surfaces impacting the plant are not damp per se but rather the air is humid. High humidity would be a more helpful issue for diagnosis if there was to be a case for adding some specific issues.